# Add/Remove Software - Where does it go?

Tags: raspbian

Using Add/Remove software. I checked "Advanced Bash Scripting Guide", great. It installs, does it's thing. Where does it put it? What is it? PDF? HTML? I'm learning Linux, working towards essentials certification, etc... I didn't want to ask this, tried more than a few things.

As in the case above, if the Add/Remove Software doesn't create a menu item under one of the various categories, then where does it install too? Specifically in this case. Where do I launch my newly installed "Advanced Bash Scripting Guide" from? Thanks ahead of time for any input.

Comment: I haven't tried find yet. I was working with grep and trying to recursively find it and found nothing. This is keeping in mind I'm totally green with these tools. What doesn't make sense to me is if I check off, say 2, 3, 1 of the "Add Software" packages, and it does it's job, am I expected to search the entire drive for where the heck it gets installed? This functionality makes ZERO sense to me. At the least I'd expect the description for the software to say where it's installed to and how to access it or launch it. Thanks, I'll give find a try too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets installed as a set of static web pages in the following directory:

**/usr/share/doc/abs-guide/**

specifically in the 'html' subdirectory. The easiest way to open this would be to use the file manager to browse to the html directory and double click the **index.html** file. This will open it in the default web browser. I would suggest bookmarking it - as it is far more than can be read completely in a single session, and will make returning to it much easier next time.

Assuming you know the package name (see below for how to determine this) You can see where a package gets installed with the following command:

```
dpkg -L <packagename>
```

so in your case:

```
dpkg -L abs-guide
```

Note: this may show more than one location. For example, it may install a config file in the /etc directory and working files in the /var directory and an executable in /usr/bin etc.

You can also use the find command to locate a file or directory:

```
sudo find / -name abs-guide
```

The above command searches the root directory and all subdirectories for files/directories named 'abs-guide'. A few notes on the above:

- I used sudo so it would allow me to search without throwing a bunch of permission errors.
- I knew to search for 'abs-guide' because that was the package name below the package title - **The Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide**.
- You can also use wildcards to match a part of the file name. for example you could search for all files/directories that end with 'guide' using the following command:

```
sudo find / -name *guide
```

Since you are new to Linux and keen on learning I would suggest that you read the man page for new/unfamiliar commands. Man pages are the built-in user documentation for Linux commands. You might want to start with `man man` (yes the man command has its own manual page). You may also want to look at `man find`, `man dpkg` and `man section 7 glob` (which discusses wildcards). Once you get the basics down TLDR pages can be installed and is a more concise form of help when you just need to see an example or a reminder of which flag or option you need.

There is a common practice, followed to varying degrees by different Linux distributions, for the Linux filesystem. This can help you make some assumptions about where a file or program is installed. Try `man 7 file-heirarchy` A good introduction and set of additional resources can be found in this [article](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/linux-filesystem-explained/) from Linux.com.

Lastly, once you are comfortable with the find command you may want to explore the `locate` and `mlocate` commands. They are often faster than `find` since they work from a prepared database instead of searching the disk. Note they will need to be installed and the database updated before use.

Comment: Thanks Steve, big time. Fantastic answer, oddly while you were writing this, on a Debian Reference Card (web page), at the top it points to the usr/share/doc dir and I found it. I will follow your advice, all of the above. I do have to ask in the end though, why the Add/Remove software doesn't just, well, spell it out in the description? Aka, after loading the package go to xyz/abc/ and execute jack.py. It just seems bizarre to me after loading up pkgs I'd have to then go out and run searches, etc... THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: You were too quick I was adding the file-hierarchy info to my answer as you typed your comment. As to your question about documenting the install and next steps, that info is available you just need to know the command to find the info - and I understand that this can seem very cryptic at first especially if you have never used a terminal in Mac or Windows. But as I mentioned in my answer a single package can install files in multiple locations and may install dozens of commands. .

Comment: Agreed with your assessment. Also I haven't done anything significant with my pi, python, bash, etc... yet as I'm still deep in "do these exercises / learn these code snippets" mode. I think, i'm thinking anyway, I just may look at creating my own mining app to surf my storage and build an index / links / what have you to all existing documentation on my pi (pdf/html/txt). Anyway, just an idea. THAN YOU AGAIN! GREAT DETAILED HELP! I copied your post into a libre doc Im saving to my desktop.